# Fetch rows with system date and state

Tags: sql, database, oracle

```
>          cycleNO| month |   year|  start date |    close date         |state | prv month  | next mnt 
>             1      4        2012    1/4/2012     30/4/2012 23:59:59      1       3                5
>             1      5        2012    1/5/2012     31/5/2012 23:59:59      0       4                6  
>             1      6        2012    1/6/2012     30/6/2012 23:59:59      0       5                7  
>             1      7        2012    1/7/2012     31/7/2012 23:59:59      0       6                8
>             2      4        2012    1/4/2012     30/4/2012 23:59:59      1       3                5
>             2      5        2012    1/5/2012     31/5/2012 23:59:59      0       4                6  
>             2      6        2012    1/6/2012     30/6/2012 23:59:59      0       5                7  
>             2      7        2012    1/7/2012     31/7/2012 23:59:59      0       6                8
```

I have a table (cycle_set) like above and want to fetch (cycleNO,month,year,start date,close date) with the condition where state =0 and start-close date which contains the system date within also the immediate next month with state =0.

Output should be :

> ```
> cycleNO | month | year | start date | close date 
> 1      5        2012    1/5/2012     31/5/2012 23:59:59
> 1      6        2012    1/6/2012     30/6/2012 23:59:59
> 2      5        2012    1/5/2012     31/5/2012 23:59:59
> 2      6        2012    1/6/2012     30/6/2012 23:59:59
> ```

Comment: Could you show an example row to be returned? Or elaborate your last sentence.

Comment: You tagged it with MySQL **and** Oracle. Which one are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select cycleNO,month,year,start_date,close_date 
FROM cycle_set
WHERE state=0 and sysdate between start_date and close_date
```

**UPDATE**: If you want to get both current and next month:

```
select cycleNO, month, year, start_date, close_date 
FROM cycle_set
WHERE state=0 
   and ( sysdate between start_date and close_date or --current month
         sysdate between add_months(start_date,-1)  and close_date --next_month
        )
```

Comment: Also I have to fetch the next cycle

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT cycleNO,month,year,start_date,close_date FROM cycle_set
WHERE state=0
AND MONTH(start_date) = (SELECT month FROM cycle_set WHERE state=0 AND...)
AND MONTH(close_date) = (SELECT month FROM cycle_set WHERE state=0 AND...)
```

The problem is, you don't have a way of selecting the next results month. What goes in the WHERE clause in those two subselects?

It would be a lot easier if you extracted all the data, then worked on it in PHP or whatever you are using.

Comment: select cycleNO,month,year,start_date,close_date from cycle_set where 
sysdate between start_date and close_date and
state=0, but how to select the next month also ?

Comment: For the next month the state will always be zero

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a data set (as shown in example):

```
    SELECT  cycleno,month,year,start_date,close_date 
      FROM  cycle_set
     WHERE  state=0 
       AND  (   month = EXTRACT(month FROM sysdate) 
             OR month = EXTRACT(month FROM sysdate)+1
            )
  ORDER BY  cycleno, month, year, start_date
```